# Folder Locked Because of OS -- How To Tell Why?

Tags: windows, permissions

A few times lately I've had the issue of a folder or file not being readable or writable (not sure atm) which then causes the application to crash or throw up an error when not being run from an admin account.

Is there a way to tell what in the world is keeping this file from being accessible?
I've tried adding the user accounts in question (and even sometimes trying full permissions to everyone) as admins on that directory (C:\troubleDirectory) to no avail.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/), it will tell you what is accessing the file and allow you to unlock it:

[image]

Comment: I've tried all the files from C: down in the path of the file in question and Unlocker says no locking handles were found. Great app though!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try making a copy of the entire folder, then renaming the two folders so that the copy is used? This could help determine if there is a deeper problem with some of the files in that folder, rather than a permissions or application issue.

Comment: Tried this and it did not resolve the issue.
The application that's having trouble is the "Labeling Program" from OCLC. (Contacting them for help is about impossible).